# How to hide data-attribute when the value of attribute is something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide the link field button when the value of the button equals to 'Work Order' see the image below.

[image]

> My HTML code:

[image]

I tried this `$("li[data-label='Work Order']").hide()` but didn't worked.

Comment: Do you want the `<a>` to *always* be hidden when that's the data attribute, or do you only want it to occur conditionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li` is not the same element as the one with the `data-label` attribute. If you want to hide the `<a>` inside, use the selector string `a[data-label='Work%20Order']`:

```js
$("a[data-label='Work%20Order']").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-label="Work%20Order">link</a>
```

You *do* need to use the `%20` inside the selector.

If you want to *always* hide such an element, you can achieve this with CSS alone - no need for jQuery or any Javascript at all. Use the same selector string plus `display: none`:

```css
a[data-label='Work%20Order'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a data-label="Work%20Order">link</a>
```

If you want to hide the whole `<li>` container when one of its children has such an attribute, then select each of those elements with jQuery and call `.parent()` on it:

```js
$("a[data-label='Work%20Order']").parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a data-label="Work%20Order">link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-label="Work%20Order">link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```